# apache fop conversion from fo file to pdf much slower on server than local and commnad line

Tags: garbage-collection, tomcat7, liferay-6, apache-fop

I am facing a strange issue where apache fop convert fo file to pdf runs very slow on server (tomcat 7 , liferay 6.2) but fast on local (tomcat 7, liferay 6.2).

on server it takes like 2mins but local only like couple seconds
also if use command line on server it is normal taking couple seconds as well.

the pdf is about 80 pages and since xsl file is too big i cannot post it here.

we have monitor GC on local and server and found that on local there are like 1 or 2 minor GC happened and on server minor GC happens every 1 or 2 seconds. and each gc release like 500m memory, so it appears that on server it generates more garbage than on local.

also when running on server , cpu usage stays at 5% almost a straight .

my code sample, try catch block ommitted :

```
fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(xconf);

FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

Fop fop;
fop =fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, outStream);
Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl().newTransformer().transform(foFile, res)
```

any thoughts will be highly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

I fixed the issue by adding something like log4j.logger.org.apache.fop = info.
we earlier had log4j.logger.org.apache set to DEBUG, so we guess it was too much logging cauesed the issue.

Comment: What memory are you giving to the processes on each system (-Xmx)?

Comment: the heap size on the server is set to 4G(newRatio, SurvivorRatio is by default) and on local it is 2G. I have tried different combination but the issue still remains.

Comment: Where do you put the log entry log4j.logger.org.apache.fop = DEBUG in liferay?